# How can I make Optionals Hashable in Xcode 9.4

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

In Xcode 10, the Swift compiler is smart enough to:

1. Treat Optionals that wrap `Hashable` values as being `Hashable`.
2. Xcode >=9.4 will also treat `struct`s that contain all `Hashable`
   properties as also being `Hashable`.

Curiously, Xcode 10 treats Optionals as Hashable even if the build language is Swift 4, or even Swift 3.

Take the following code for example:

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    var string1: String?
    var string2: String?
}
```

That code compiles under Xcode 10, and using the hashValue of a Foo object works as expected, even if the build language is Swift 3!

However, in Xcode 9.4, the Foo struct is not automatically Hashable unless you make the properties non-optional.

This code compiles and works as you would want it to in Xcode 9.4/Swift 4.1:

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    var string1: String
    var string2: String
}
```

How can I make optionals `Hashable` in Xcode 9? I could certainly implement `Hashable` conformance for my struct myself, but creating good hashes for multi-part structures is actually kinda tricky, and I would like to not have to worry about it.

I also can't think of a straightforward way to make an Optional `Hashable`. (again, this is only an issue in Xcode < Xcode 10. My employer has not yet moved to Xcode 10, so I need a solution that works for Xcode 9.4)

Comment: You're confusing Xcode versions with Swift versions. Even if you use Xcode 10 you can still use Swift 3. I guess you're asking about how to do this in Swift 4.0 or Swift 4.1 instead of Swift 4.2? Please don't confuse IDE versions with language/compiler versions, it's two very different concepts. Swift can also be compiled outside of Xcode (and maybe you should try this to narrow down your problem)

Comment: Also probably related (Swift 4.2), https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md and https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md (also Swift 4.2)

Comment: I understand the difference quite well. You would think the language version would determine what works and what doesn't, but I specifically tested it. It appears to be driven by the version of the compiler rather than the version of the language that you select in the IDE. In Xcode 10, even if you select Swift 3 as your language version, the version of the struct with optionals compiles, where in Xcode 9.4 it won't compile.

Comment: Until you upgrade, use Sourcery's AutoHashable (https://cdn.rawgit.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/master/docs/hashable.html). When you upgrade, this is easy to remove and replace with implicit Hashable.

Comment: I used "Xcode 10" and "Xcode 9.4" because I don't have ready access to info about the compiler versions included in those versions of the IDE, and it describes the situation I found.  If you have that info it would be helpful. (I almost always use the LLVM Swift compiler from within Xcode, unless I'm building a project with brew, or doing Swift on a Pi.

Comment: Try the version of the struct with the optionals in it in Xcode 9.4, and then try it in Xcode 10 with the language version set to Swift 3. You'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: If you just want to do Sourcery "by hand," they include their combineHashValues here: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/blob/master/Templates/Templates/AutoHashable.stencil

Comment: But seriously, upgrade! It's time! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183331/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-rob-napier).

Comment: @matt, that's why I want to leverage the Hashable feature of structs in Swift 4.1 and not try to roll my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 4.2** defines the conditional `Optional: Hashable` conformance in
[Optional.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-4.2-branch/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L412)
as

```
extension Optional: Hashable where Wrapped: Hashable {
  //  ...
  public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    switch self {
    case .none:
      hasher.combine(0 as UInt8)
    case .some(let wrapped):
      hasher.combine(1 as UInt8)
      hasher.combine(wrapped)
    }
  }
}
```

In particular

- `.none` has the same hash value as the integer zero, independent of the
  type, and
- the hash value `.some(wrapped)` is obtained by mixing the hash value of
  `wrapped` with that of the integer one.

**Swift 4.1** (which comes with Xcode 9.4) has already the necessary tools to
implement a similar method:

- Conditional conformance, i.e. we can define an extension

  ```
  extension Optional: Hashable where Wrapped: Hashable
  ```
- Automatic synthesis of `Hashable` for types if all members are `Hashable`.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
extension Optional: Hashable where Wrapped: Hashable {
    struct Combiner: Hashable {
        let left: Int
        let right: Wrapped
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return 0.hashValue
        case .some(let wrapped):
            return Combiner(left: 1, right: wrapped).hashValue
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct Foo: Hashable {
    var string1: String?
    var string2: String?
}

let foo = Foo(string1: "1", string2: "2")
print(foo.hashValue) // 2171695307022640119
```

To make this code compile with Swift 4.2 and newer as well, the
extension method can be conditionally compiled (compare
[SE-0212 Compiler Version Directive](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0212-compiler-version-directive.md)):

```
#if swift(>=4.1.50) || (swift(>=3.4) && !swift(>=4.0))
// Code targeting the Swift 4.2 compiler and above:
// Conditional conformance `Optional: Hashable` defined in the standard library.
#elseif swift(>=4.1) || (swift(>=3.3) && !swift(>=4.0))
// Code targeting the Swift 4.1 compiler and above:

extension Optional: Hashable where Wrapped: Hashable {
    // ...
}

#endif
```

Comment: Outstanding. (voted). That's what I was looking for. One question though: In the Swift 4.2 version of Optional's Hashable extension, for the .some case it combines the hash of 1 and the hash of the wrapped value. (I assume that's to make `foo` and `Optional<Foo>` have  different hashes.) Your version doesn't include that step. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @DuncanC: It does already, with `Combiner(left: 1, right: wrapped).hashValue`. The hash combiner function is not public, therefore I used that “trick” of a local struct. You can check that `foo.hashValue` and `(foo as Foo?).hashValue` are different. – You are welcome, it was fun to figure it out!